# TF Dataset : Sharding after shuffle, with a random seed

Tags: tensorflow, keras, distributed-computing, distributed, sharding

The [TF documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shard) says that when Sharding :

> Be sure to shard before you use any randomizing operator (such as shuffle).

That makes sense since we want to ensure that each process gets unique data.

But if I shard with a **seed**, would that be OK ?

Thanks

Liam